# clientCache cachecontrolmode="UseMaxAge" returns ridiculous max-age number

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, web-config

I'm trying to use clientCache with cacheControlMode = UseMaxAge, like this in my web.config:

```
  <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="0.00:05:00" cacheControlCustom="public" setEtag="false"  />
```

However, in one of our production servers, the Response Header always returns like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: public, max-age=63610542360
```

The max-age should be 300. In other server we have it works fine with the same application files and web.config deployed.

Have anyone had the same problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the server was with .Net Framework 4.6 installed. The server where it worked was with .Net Framework 4.5 installed. I just downgraded to .Net Framework 4.5 and max-age is now working. 
I don't know if it's a bug from the 4.6 version.